how to set <p></p> format for a parameter using AXIOS with Node.js?
Please help me with this issue. :) Thank you!
Im calling a recipe from https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Get-Random-Recipes
when i call the summary parameter inside a  i get the paragraph without format.
Example:
this is how i got it in the browser
My index.js code:
app.post("/random", async (req, res) => {
    
    try {
        const result = await axios.get(random + apiKey);
        const recipeObject = result.data.recipes[0];       
        res.render("index.ejs", { recipe: recipeObject });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render("index.ejs", { recipe: recipeObject })
    }
    
});


and my index.ejs code:
<div class="container">
                <form id="myForm" method="post">              
                    <label for="submit">Prueba tu suerte y elige tu próxima receta:</label>
                    <input id="random" type="submit" value="Elige por mi" formaction="/random"> 
                  </form>
</div>
            <div class="response-area">
                <p class="texto-receta">
                    <% if (locals.recipe) { %>
                        <img src="<%= recipe.image %>" alt="">
                    </br>
                        Recipe #:  <%= recipe.id %>
                        </br>
                        Name:  <%= recipe.title %>
                        </br>
                        Preparation time: <%= recipe.readyInMinutes %> minutes
                        </br>
                        Serving size: <%= recipe.servings %>
                    </br>
                    Healthy level: <%= recipe.healthyScore %>
                    </br>
                </br>
            <b> Summary:</b> <%= recipe.summary %>
                </br>
                        
                    <% }else{%>
                    No hay receta para hoy. Inténtalo de nuevo pronto.
                  <% }%>
                </p>
              </div>


i want it to get all working, the styles and diferentes lables in the text like this
and this is the result with styles i want
This is my first test with API, im searching how to solve it on internet but without results :´).

At first I thought that the link that supposedly already answered this question is kinda random, but then I realized. You just need to replace <%= recipe.summary %> with <%- recipe.summary %> (ejs tag is different).
